# Can I run NEO4J on a t2.micro AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I had `NEO4J` running on a m3.medium instance, only to realizes that I was being charged for `AWS` usage.  No issue here.  Since I am experimenting at this time, I'd like to run `NEO4J` on the t2.micro instance.  I followed instructions on `AWS` to resize to a t2.micro instance and now I cannot access the `NEO4J` server. My `NEO4J` stack is up and running, but I get a `503 service unavailable error`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I assume you're able to SSH in?  Did you bind Neo4j to 0.0.0.0 or the original IP address?  Unless you allocated an Elastic IP address, when you shutdown, resized and started it again, you got a new IP address.  Try bumping it up to a t2.small or t2.medium and see if Neo4j comes up then?  Unless you have a lot of data in it, Neo4j should start up just fine on a micro.  In fact, even with a lot of data, I think it will still start up, I don't believe Neo4j aggressively loads all of its data upfront.

Answer (score 4):

Neo4j should run fine on t2.micro. I have it even running on Raspberry PI for demo purposes. You just need to take care on setting right heap size and pagecache size. Maybe go with 512M for heap and 200M for pagecache, leaving up ~300 for the system.

If all memory is occupied, sshd cannot allocate memory for new connections.